# JXLS elseif or continue

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I am writing a template and want to use else if or continue statement in the statement.
I have a for loop in template and under for loop , i hv multiple if  conditions, i want to  skip  checking all if conditions if one condition is met, i tried using else if  but looks like jxls do not support, any other way to use else if or continue statement in for loop in template of jxls

```
<jx:forEach items="${liste}" var="a">
<jx:if test="${a.data==1}">
</jx :if>
<jx:if test="${a.data==2}">
</jx :if>
<jx:if test="${a.data==3}">
</jx :if>
</jx:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

jxls use JEXL Syntax https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html

Ex, to if else you can use ternary operation

```
<jx:forEach items="${liste}" var="a"> 
${a.data == a || a.data == b || a.data == c ? 'yes': 'no'}
</jx:forEach>
```